# Is there any statistical data on the most common Android version on tablets?

Tags: android, version, tablet

I am aware of the following link ([here](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)), which shows the up-to-date coverage on the various Android versions (what ratio of devices out there are running the various levels). However, it covers Android as a whole, on both phones and tablets.

I'm wondering if there's a similar thing for tablets only. I have an application which makes sense only for a certain screen size and phones don't really cut it. So I'm looking for the best version of Android to target for tablets only.

If the info is not available, I'll probably have to go for 2.3.3, based on the link above, but I'd prefer some hard data since I *suspect* the most common tablet version is likely to be skewed towards later versions (due to their more recent appearance and capabilities).

Comment: Bods, closing this as not constructive seems a bit bizarre, since it very much asks for something requiring "facts, references, or specific expertise". I'm not asking for supposition as to which is the best version, I'm asking if there's _hard data_ available on Android usage on tablets. How you could interpret that as "opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" is beyond me. I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Still Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Not for surveys.

Comment: I'm not doing a survey - I don't want a bucket load of answers like  "I have a Xoom and am running 4.0.1". I'm after a _definitive_ link with information, if available. In my opinion, this is covered in the FAQ: "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession". Still, if it gets closed, I'll defer to the swarm :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also wish to look at these comparisons:

- http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/android-versions-comparison
- http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/mobile-os-comparison-developer-view
- http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/android-3-honeycomb-tablets

Comment: That last link seems a good one since it places a lower limit of Android 3 on the vast majority of those devices.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't provide what you are asking for as they don't differentiate on tablets and phones. If you are going to have any chance finding something like this you have to go through the major brands of tablets and see what versions they support. I don't know if flurry or some other data source might have gathered such information but I highly doubt it.

Edit: I found this [link](http://blog.flurry.com/bid/81151/Amazon-Lights-the-Android-World-on-Fire). Based on the data we could calculate the most popular version.

Kindle 36% = 2.3

Samsung galaxy tab 36% = Stock 2.2, upgrade 2.3

Asus transformer 7% = upgrade 4.x

Acer 7% = Different version, many above 2.3

Motorola = Above 2.3

Other 10% = unknown

And these data is from January 2012

Comment: Actually, that's not too bad an idea. I can choose the top ten (or N) devices and then figure out the latest Android versions they support. That should give me a feel for the largest coverage.

Comment: @paxdiablo I've added some findings based on the january data from flurry. But the market has changed a lot since then but I don't think the version has gone down in version :)